# I want to create an object to leave in a new thread the main thread will need to communicate with that object, the object's function need to run on it

Tags: c++, multithreading, pybind11

Currently I have a main object/class - server, which uses a secondary object which acts as a worker.
This server runs in python, the worker is written in c++ but using python bindings, I create the object with python on the server. The server when it has a new client sends users the worker object to get the work done, the worker responds back and this goes on, as its streaming data.

Now I want to make this work with many workers. I will create an orchestration layer above my current worker, where I will spin up new threads and put each worker in a new thread.
Then when a new client comes, I have the server speak with a specific thread, and thus I can support many clients concurrently.

My issue is, how will I spin up this worker object in a new thread?
If I just create it in a new thread, the thread will finish and exit making the worker object not valid.
I want to keep the object alive in that thread but without it doing anything. Only when the server calls the object to do something, and this work will happen in this new thread.

I tried a silly implementation to see can I can make the server thread communicate with the client.
This works but this keeps the worker busy looping, while I want it to react to when it gets called.

silly example (no where near the real case)

```
#include <unistd.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

class worker {
 public:
  int x = 3;

  worker(int k) : x{k} {};

  void SetX(int l) { x = l; }
  int getX() { return x; }
};
void foo(int x) { std::cout << "num=" << x << "\n"; }
void printloop(std::shared_ptr<worker> s_ptr) {
  auto k = s_ptr.get();
  while (1) {
    std::cout << "numb=" << k->getX() << "\n";
    sleep(3);
  }
}
int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<worker> r = std::make_shared<worker>(2);

  std::thread th1(printloop, r);

  int i = 0;
  while (i < 5) {
    r.get()->SetX(i);
    sleep(1);
    i++;
  }

  th1.join();
  std::cout << "x = " << r.get()->getX() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interthread communications is actually a complicated subject, and all rules of interthread synchronization must be properly implemented, using mutexes and condition variables. This is a large topic that can't be summarized in just one or two paragraphs, on Stackoverflow. You will find more information in your advanced multithreading textbook.

Comment: Is a 1-to-1 association between clients and workers necessary? Otherwise just have clients dump work on a shared queue, have a threadpool full of workers blocking on the queue, and provide a way to communicate results back (eg `std::future`)

Comment: Yeah its necessary, although that is one solution I was thinking about too.

Answer (score -1):

If i understood your problem correctly there is a solution in POSIX Threads (pthreads) and it is called "Condition Variables" (cv).

What is a condition variable used for? The answer is Thread Synchronization. By using CV's you can ensure a thread is run when a condition (signal) occurs. If that criteria is not met than the thread wait on sleep. This is an example from the CMU (Carnegie Mellon University).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t count_mutex     = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t condition_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  condition_cond  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *functionCount1();
void *functionCount2();
int  count = 0;
#define COUNT_DONE  10
#define COUNT_HALT1  3
#define COUNT_HALT2  6

main()
{
   pthread_t thread1, thread2;

   pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &functionCount1, NULL);
   pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, &functionCount2, NULL);
   pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
   pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

   exit(0);
}

void *functionCount1()
{
   for(;;)
   {
      pthread_mutex_lock( &condition_mutex );
      while( count >= COUNT_HALT1 && count <= COUNT_HALT2 )
      {
         pthread_cond_wait( &condition_cond, &condition_mutex );
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock( &condition_mutex );

      pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );
      count++;
      printf("Counter value functionCount1: %d\n",count);
      pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );

      if(count >= COUNT_DONE) return(NULL);
    }
}

void *functionCount2()
{
    for(;;)
    {
       pthread_mutex_lock( &condition_mutex );
       if( count < COUNT_HALT1 || count > COUNT_HALT2 )
       {
          pthread_cond_signal( &condition_cond );
       }
       pthread_mutex_unlock( &condition_mutex );

       pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );
       count++;
       printf("Counter value functionCount2: %d\n",count);
       pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );

       if(count >= COUNT_DONE) return(NULL);
    }

}
```

In this example the `pthread_cond_wait( &condition_cond, &condition_mutex );` on the functionCount1() ensures a wait on the "signal" on the functionCount2(). Signaling is done by  `pthread_cond_signal( &condition_cond );`

Condition Variables are kind of a complex topic therefore for more knowladge please visit [IBM Condition Variable](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=ssw_ibm_i_73/apis/users_78.html), which i believe has a good explanation.

Comment: Are you aware that the standard library already provides a [concurrency support library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) which includes `std::thread`, `std::mutex`, `std::condition_variable` and (a lot) more ?

Comment: Sorry but this is not useful for my case. Thanks for trying though.